# How to list all nodes with alphabetical headings?

Tags: views

I want to list all nodes with alphabetical headings like this example http://www.animeseason.com/anime-list/
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the Views module (http://drupal.org/project/views) which actually comes with a pre-built view called "Glossary". Enable that and tweak it to suit your needs.

Hope this helps.