# How can I loop through Drupal 7 Views to add anchor tags to an alphabetical list

Tags: views

I'm attempting to create anchor tags for a views 3 rendered list of content where each change in the first character of the title gets an 
`<a name="a"></a>` or "b" or "c" added to the html output.

The only way I've found to be outside the foreach loop where I can monitor the change in the title is in a preprocess function like this:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $alphc = 'a';
  $target = "<a name='$alphc'></a>";

  foreach( $vars['view']->result as $key => $values) {
    $title = $values->node_title;
    $tmp = substr($title,0,1);

    if (strtolower($tmp) != $alphc) {
      $alphc = strtolower($tmp);
      $target = "<a name='$alphc'></a>";
          ...
        }
```

The problem of course is that Views has already rendered the html output in $rows.
I'm sure I'm not the first person trying to do this since having a series of links A B C D E F G H etc. to long list of content is pretty standard html practice. I'm not sure what the value of a preprocess function is if the html content has already been rendered, a preprocess function seems an ideal place to override the output.

The closest I got to a solution was with the above code and then adding a new $variable to the views->result array but I have no idea how to capture that $variable in a Views theme (display, style, row or field) so that I can append the anchor tag for the title.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
Eric

Comment: After posting I found this link and answer on StackExchange: [link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6337/how-to-list-all-nodes-with-alphabetical-headings)

I still would like to know if you can interrogate the fields in a view through a loop over all the results in a function call rather than having this buried in the Views rendered $rows (html text) output where the html is next to impossible to alter.

Comment: yes, you can use the pre_render hook: http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7

Comment: You can find all the hooks for Views [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/7).